# how to fix FATAL ERROR in native method in java

Tags: java

How can I fix this error message in java?

The notes will descend from the top vertically in the 4 lanes. The player has to press the corresponding arrow key
when the note overlaps with the stationary note symbol at the bottom. The accuracy of how close
the note was to the stationary note when the key was pressed, will determine the points given.
There will be special hold notes that require the player to hold down the key. To win, the player
needs to beat the target score when all the notes have fallen. If the player’s score is lower, the
game ends.

Thanks

`FATAL ERROR in native method: Thread[main,5,main]: No context is current or a function that is not available in the current context was called. The JVM will abort execution. at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.nglGenTextures(Native Method) at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.glGenTextures(GL11C.java:667) at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGenTextures(GL11.java:2439)`

```
import bagel.*;
import bagel.util.Point;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;



public class ShadowDance extends AbstractGame  {
    private final static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
    private final static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 768;
    private final static String GAME_TITLE = "SHADOW DANCE";
    private final Image BACKGROUND_IMAGE = new Image("res/background.png");

    private final static Font TITLE_FONT = new Font("res/FSO8BITR.ttf", 64);
    private final static Font INSTRUCTION_FONT = new Font("res/FSO8BITR.ttf", 24);
    private final static String INSTRUCTION = "PRESS SPACE TO START\nUSE ARROW KEYS TO PLAY";
    private final static Point TITLE_POINT = new Point(220,260);
    private final static Point INSTRUCTION_POINT = new Point(320,450);

    private final static String WORLD_FILE = "res/level1.csv";

    //a value to indicate the game has started or not
    private boolean start = false;

    private LaneLeft laneLeft;
    private LaneRight laneRight;
    private LaneDown laneDown;
    private LaneUp laneUp;
    private final static String LEFT = "Left";
    private final static String RIGHT = "Right";
    private final static String DOWN = "Down";
    private final static String UP = "Up";

    public ShadowDance(){
        super(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, GAME_TITLE);
        this.start = start;
        readCSV();
    }

    /**
     * Method used to read file and create objects (you can change
     * this method as you wish).
     */
    private boolean readCSV() {
       try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(WORLD_FILE))) {
            String text;
            //find each lane's x coordinate

            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String lanes[] = text.split(",");
                if(lanes[0].equals("Lane")){
                    if (lanes[1].equals(LEFT)){
                        laneLeft = new LaneLeft(Double.parseDouble(lanes[2]));
                    }else if (lanes[1].equals(RIGHT)){
                        laneRight = new LaneRight(Double.parseDouble(lanes[2]));
                    }else if (lanes[1].equals(UP)){
                        laneUp = new LaneUp(Double.parseDouble(lanes[2]));
                    }else if (lanes[1].equals(DOWN)){
                        laneDown = new LaneDown(Double.parseDouble(lanes[2]));
                    }
                    start = true;
                }       
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return start;
    }


    /**
     * The entry point for the program.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShadowDance game = new ShadowDance();
        game.run();
    }

    /**
     * Performs a state update.
     * Allows the game to exit when the escape key is pressed.
     */
    @Override
    protected void update(Input input) {
        if (input.wasPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)){
            Window.close();
        }

        BACKGROUND_IMAGE.draw(Window.getWidth()/2.0, Window.getHeight()/2.0);

        if (start == false){
            /**
             *render title and instruction message
             */
            TITLE_FONT .drawString(GAME_TITLE, TITLE_POINT.x, TITLE_POINT.y);
            INSTRUCTION_FONT.drawString(INSTRUCTION, INSTRUCTION_POINT.x, INSTRUCTION_POINT.y);
            if(input.wasPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
                start = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            laneLeft.update();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried make a game called shadow dance now I am trying to load lane images

Comment: all the code that is commented out in your question, is that also commented out in the code you run?

Comment: yes, they are all commented out

Comment: I don't know what AbstractGame does but the error message is complaining that it cannot load textures in the current GL Context or there is no Context. Too bad it doesn't tell you which of those things were the case! Most likely there is something wrong with the setup that gets the OpenGL native libraries loaded.

Comment: also, I would add the tags OpenGL and whatever framework AbstractGame comes from to the tag list